# Why can't a Deferred be passed to a callback in Python Twisted?

Tags: python, twisted, deferred-execution

```
d = Deferred()
d.callback(Deferred()) # Assertion error saying that a Deferred shouldn't be passed
```

Why is this? I looked through the code and commit messages / Trac and see no reason why this should be the case. The most obvious way to bypass this is to put the `Deferred` in a tuple, but why is this restriction here in the first place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two related reasons for this.

First, it helps catch what is likely a mistake early - near the place where the mistake is being made.  A Deferred is called back with a result which is then passed to all of its callbacks.  If you make the result itself a Deferred, then there's not much these callbacks can do when they're called.  This leads me to the next reason.

Second, Deferreds support be *chaining* which handles the most common use cases one might have for passing in a Deferred.  Given two Deferreds, a and b, chaining causes a to pause processing its own callback chain until b has a result, then a resumes its callback chain with the result of b.  This is what happens when a callback on a Deferred returns a Deferred.  It can also be done explicitly with `Deferred.chainDeferred`.